# Problem with input method

Tags: 12.04

In some input boxes I can't type. If I right-click on input box I can see input methods, where IBUS is selected. If I select "None" instead, everything is fine.

How can I turn this IBUS method off globally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running on the command line,

```
im-switch
```

This will let you set per-user the input method.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick - I set input method to None then it (zenity dialog) crashed - segfaulted. I removed it, and also removed all input methods I saw available, and wonder why I had those thai input methods and some Chinese in Language settings,  when I sure didn't select any other language then English. But not that much curious ;) Cheers