# How to remove libthai-data?

Tags: 12.04

This seem like bigger problem then expected. I had problem with input dialog boxes [problem-with-input-method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131056/problem-with-input-method) when I learned that I had some Chinese language in language preferences and couple of Thai input methods.

I started to remove all related data, many thai fonts, additional input methods, and when I selected `libthai-data` from Synaptic, now it wants to remove more then 100 packages, everything I have installed including Unity, Compiz, Nautilus, Firefox...

I installed 12.04 on clean formated hard drive on the day it was announced, without selecting anything exotic, like other language then English and similar

Any suggestions?

---

Also when some dialog in Nautilus (not sure if it's globally) pops, then buttons are placed opposite than they should, and then quickly roll to normal position. I assume it's related to this issue, and also think that there must be some bug report already, as I downloaded ISO image from Ubuntu site normally, and followed simple installation instruction without tweaking anything.

Answer (score 1):

It's old `libpango` issue by some and feature by others:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pango1.0/+bug/509919
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pango1.0/+bug/510354

Removing seems like insane task

Answer (score 0):

libthai-data is a dependency of libthai which is a dependency of Firefox.  So I'm afraid it's going to have to stay if you want to keep Firefox.  However it's very small and won't affect your input methods, so I would recommend just leaving it where it is.

Comment: It's not dependency, it's just suggestion/recommendation. I have still no idea why is this package installed, and why it removal wants to remove almost everything, like Unity, Compiz, etc. Will investigate later, and maybe rephrase question